# Rebuilt a list of dictionary

Tags: json, list, split, ansible

I can't rebuild a list of dictionary in Ansible code as below:

Input:

```json
{
    "list_report": [
        {
            "objectid": "8502d7d99a435532", 
            "value": "10.70.108.15,10.70.106.10,10.72.106.167"
        }
    ]
}
```

To have in output:

```json
{
    "list_report": [
        {
            "objectid": "8502d7d99a435532", 
            "value": [10.70.108.15,10.70.106.10,10.72.106.167]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I need to keep item: `objectid` as it is, but, I want to change item: `value` from string to a list of IPs. I tried a lot of solution but nothing seems to work.

Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you did not over simplified your example input, you could just split the value using Python's [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    list_report: 
      - objectid: "8502d7d99a435532"
        value: "10.70.108.15,10.70.106.10,10.72.106.167"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        list_report: "{{ 
          [{
            'objectid': list_report.0.objectid, 
            'value': list_report.0.value.split(',')
          }] 
        }}"
    
    - debug:
        var: list_report
```

This yields:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "list_report": [
        {
            "objectid": "8502d7d99a435532",
            "value": [
                "10.70.108.15",
                "10.70.106.10",
                "10.72.106.167"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Now, if you have more than one item in this array, you can resort to a temporary variable.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    list_report: 
      - objectid: "8502d7d99a435532"
        value: "10.70.108.15,10.70.106.10,10.72.106.167"
      - objectid: "8502d7d99a435533"
        value: "10.70.108.16,10.70.106.11,10.72.106.168"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        _list_report: "{{ 
          _list_report | default([]) + 
          [{
            'objectid': item.objectid,
            'value': item.value.split(',')
          }]
        }}"
      loop: "{{ list_report }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.objectid }}"

    - set_fact:
        list_report: "{{ _list_report }}"
    
    - debug:
        var: list_report
```

This yields the reacp:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=8502d7d99a435532)
ok: [localhost] => (item=8502d7d99a435533)

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  list_report:
  - objectid: 8502d7d99a435532
    value:
    - 10.70.108.15
    - 10.70.106.10
    - 10.72.106.167
  - objectid: 8502d7d99a435533
    value:
    - 10.70.108.16
    - 10.70.106.11
    - 10.72.106.168

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I can admin that I never tough  to this solution, just another think, if I have a more that one netry in dict m how can I apply you idea:
{
    "list_report": [
        {
            "objectid": "8502d7d99a435532", 
            "value": [10.70.108.15,10.70.106.10,10.72.106.167]
        }
        {
            "objectid": "xxxx", 
            "value": xxxxx
        }
        {
            "objectid": ".....", 
            "value":.......,......,.....
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @MohamedBouraoui answer edited for this situation, with a temporary variable.

Comment: thank a lot, I compared your awsome response to mine and I figure out that I used {{item.objectid}} instead of juste item.objectid. Thanks a lots tou save me a whole day to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For example, given the list

```yaml
    list_report:
      - objectid: "8502d7d99a435532"
        value: "10.70.108.15,10.70.106.10,10.72.106.167"
      - objectid: "8502d7d99a435533"
        value: "10.70.108.16,10.70.106.11,10.72.106.168"
```

the task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list_report: "{{ dict(_objs|zip(_vals))|
                         dict2items(key_name='objectid', value_name='value') }}"
      vars:
        _objs: "{{ list_report|map(attribute='objectid')|list }}"
        _vals: "{{ list_report|map(attribute='value')|map('split', ',')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list_report:
  - objectid: 8502d7d99a435532
    value:
    - 10.70.108.15
    - 10.70.106.10
    - 10.72.106.167
  - objectid: 8502d7d99a435533
    value:
    - 10.70.108.16
    - 10.70.106.11
    - 10.72.106.168
```